# What Oracle dictionary table contains table privilege information?

Tags: oracle

For example, when I go to a table's properties in sql developer, I can see what are the users (owners) have been granted the access to this table.

If I want to use a query to find all these information for a group of tables and see what users have the access to them, which Oracle data dictionary table can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be [`DBA_TAB_PRIVS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4151.htm#REFRN23282) for all objects or [`USER_TAB_PRIVS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4467.htm#REFRN26282) for the objects the current user is the owner, grantor, or grantee of.

Answer (score 0):

A good thing with the *dictionary* is that you can select from it, literally. For example (which is kind of *unreadable* because I set  columns to fit the screen; GUI is better for that):

```
SQL> select table_name, comments
  2  from dictionary
  3  where lower(comments) like '%grant%';

TABLE_NAME           COMMENTS
-------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
ALL_COL_PRIVS        Grants on columns for which the user is the grantor, grantee
                     , owner,
                      or an enabled role or PUBLIC is the grantee

ALL_COL_PRIVS_MADE   Grants on columns for which the user is owner or grantor
ALL_COL_PRIVS_RECD   Grants on columns for which the user, PUBLIC or enabled role
                      is the grantee

ALL_TAB_PRIVS        Grants on objects for which the user is the grantor, grantee
                     , owner,
                      or an enabled role or PUBLIC is the grantee

ALL_TAB_PRIVS_MADE   User's grants and grants on user's objects
ALL_TAB_PRIVS_RECD   Grants on objects for which the user, PUBLIC or enabled role
                      is the grantee

USER_AUDIT_STATEMENT Audit trail records concerning  grant, revoke, audit, noaudi
                     t and alter system

USER_COL_PRIVS       Grants on columns for which the user is the owner, grantor o
                     r grantee

USER_COL_PRIVS_MADE  All grants on columns of objects owned by the user
USER_COL_PRIVS_RECD  Grants on columns for which the user is the grantee
USER_ROLE_PRIVS      Roles granted to current user
USER_SYS_PRIVS       System privileges granted to current user
USER_TAB_PRIVS       Grants on objects for which the user is the owner, grantor o
                     r grantee

USER_TAB_PRIVS_MADE  All grants on objects owned by the user
USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD  Grants on objects for which the user is the grantee
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES    Grants on columns for which the user is the grantor, grantee
                     , owner, or
                      an enabled role or PUBLIC is the grantee

ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS      Roles which are granted to roles
ROLE_SYS_PRIVS       System privileges granted to roles
ROLE_TAB_PRIVS       Table privileges granted to roles
TABLE_PRIVILEGES     Grants on objects for which the user is the grantor, grantee
                     , owner,
                      or an enabled role or PUBLIC is the grantee


20 rows selected.

SQL>
```